# Set an ImageView position - Android

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to create some interactivity on a simple application so I can reposition an image. After doing some googling I found what should be capable of making this work but I seem unable to get anything to work. With the current code, my client will crash but I will strangely get no errors outputted at all.

Check this [link](http://pastie.org/8788281). What have I done wrong?

I am using the [following](http://pastie.org/8789041) xml to draw the image

I have also attempted to use this alongside the `setX` and `setY` methods that are a default in `ImageView`, yet they aren't recognised at all when I attempt to run. Hence I am looking into more complex code snippets.

Comment: Hey, why are you posting this over at [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1yzf2a/how_to_set_the_position_of_an_imageview/) in the vain hope of getting a speedy response... *just sayin*

Comment: Four hours. Very impatient, yes.

Comment: *Internet must be very serious business*...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast from LinearLayout.LayoutParams to AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams , this is probably the error you get .

Change the AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams because the imageView is in a linearLayout, also 
AbsoluteLayout is deprecated.

If you want to move a view (change the position) dynamically, use the translateX and translateY properties.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Edit: I am able to launch the application, but I am unable to have any response from my image. It just sits there happy as larry and I am getting no error outputs, only a lack of interaction. Do I have a logical fault somewhere? Seems most likely but I'm not sure what it may be...

Comment: This is after I have altered the code for LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have included a widget (in your case an ImageView) into the xml layout, it gets bound to that view. It is easier (and good practice) to dynamically add widgets when you need to move/remove/replace them during run time. For example you could keep your RelativeLayout container empty in your layout file and add this ImageView in your onCreate() method using RelativeLayout.addView().

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be ( if using more than 3.0),

```
imageView.animate().translateX()
```

the `animate()` would return you a ViewPropertyAnimator.

If you are using `FrameLayout` your approach of `LayoutParams` will also work.